# aws run-instances in different availability zones

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

How can I launch a set of instances **having each into a different AZ** in EC2-Classic using the AWS CLI?

According to [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/run-instances.html) documentation, using `--placement AvailabilityZone=us-west-2c` allows me to specify one AZ, but what if I also use `--count 3` and want each in different AZ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The traditional way to do this is to use **Amazon EC2 Auto Scaling**.

Auto Scaling can be configured to run EC2 servers across multiple Availability Zones. In addition, if a server fails (or if an Availability Zone fails), it can automatically launch replacement servers.

If you do *not* wish to use Auto Scaling, you will need to **use separate API calls** to launch instances in each Availability Zone.

Alternatively, you could use **AWS CloudFormation**, which can launch a collection of infrastructure in your account. One template can launch instances in different availability zones (but would need separate specifications, just like issuing multiple API calls).